# GetListItems not returning empty fields even when using ViewFields

Tags: caml-query, caml

I am using the `GetListItems` web service to query a list.

I am passing the `viewFields` property to return certain fields:

```
var viewFields = XElement.Parse(@"
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <FieldRef Name='Field2' />
    <FieldRef Name='Field3' />
  </ViewFields>
  ");

var result = client.GetListItems(listname, null, null, viewFields, null, null, null);
```

The problem is when these fields are empty or null, SharePoint does not return them, even though they are specified in ViewFields. Am I missing anything? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a field whose name exceeds 32 characters? There are problems with these fields names in SharePoint 2010 only when used in ViewFields clause.

Comment: Actually my fields do exceed 32 characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've looked at this but I think you need to indicate the Field can be null or empty

```
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='Field1' />
    <FieldRef Name='Field2' Nullable='True' />
    <FieldRef Name='Field3' Nullable='True' />
  </ViewFields>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, unfortunately this is not working for me, even though it seems like the proper solution based on your answer and this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.viewfields(v=office.14).aspx and this other one http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26479/caml-possible-to-query-non-existing-field